# How to store information: a database or your apps memory?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, memory

I've been wondering about this a lot.

So I made a database for my Android application. What is the big advantage to this over just making all the information into strings and retrieving them that way?

Or is there no advantage at all?

Comment: Depends. Do you need to change the data at runtime? Does that need to persist? Does the data fit into memory all at once? Do you want to run interesting queries?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/why-use-a-database-instead-of-just-saving-your-data-to-disk) on Programmers SE. It doesn't directly hit database vs active memory, but it does cover the advantages of using a database.

Answer (score 2):

If you have single record, as is the case with "Settings" and "Preferences", then, I guess you could store it as a properties file or JSON string in file system, or more preferably as "Shared Preferences".

However, if you have multiple records, let's say you are keeping track list of friends the current user has, then, database will be ideal, as it will allow you to create queries, create cursors for lists, and many more advantages.

Answer (score 0):

The advantages to using a local DB (this can just be a key/value store, or a full RDBMS) are that you don't need to keep all of the data in memory at one time, and also that the data is separate from the main application logic.

If you store all of your info as strings in the Android app then, as far as I know, they are all loaded into memory when the app starts. There may be ways around this, but it's far easier to use a DB (or any local file storage on the device)